# RSA в блочном режиме в случае большого исходного текста

Tags: криптография, rsa

Как устроены современные имплементации RSA? А именно, создаются ли какие-либо обертки на случай превышения выбранного модуля(N) при шифровании открытым ключом?

Т.е что происходит, если выбрранные параметры не позволяют зашифровать за 1 проход весь текст(т.к текст слишком большой)? Логика подсказывает, что обертки(в браузерах, например) именно разбивают текст по приемлемой длине, и каждый блок шифруется отдельно. Так ли это? И если да, но не предусмотрены на этот случай какие-либо режимы блочной зависмости, как в AES - CBC,EBC,OFB и т.д?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В тех реализациях с RSA, что я видел (а они довольно специфичны и очень вероятно имеют прямое отношение к тому что вы делаете) исходные данные разбивались на блоки и шифровался каждый блок отдельно. Режимы типа CBC не встречались ни разу, я их и в криптолибах не видел.

Comment: Т.е поблочное шифрование, затем шифрованные блоки склеиваются обратно и передаются?

Comment: @0xFFh в общем да.